# Why some openstack instances use the commands 'openstack server list|grep [ip]' or 'nova list|grep [ip]' can not be found

Tags: openstack

Why are some openstack instances found in the "dashboard" and viewed using the command 'nova list --ip [ip]', but not found using the command 'openstack server list|grep [ip]', 'nova list|grep [ip]'?

Comment: Interesting command, I haven't used it before but it doesn't really work as expected on some deployments, on others it does. Not sure what the criteria are when it works and when not.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say for sure what the cause of your problem is from the information you provided.

However, `nova list` and `openstack server list` both default to listing instances for the current project only.  To list instances for all projects, you need to include the `--all-tenants` or `--all-projects` option respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the Nova list command command to select parameter parameters:
--limit 
Maximum number of servers to display. If limit == -1, all servers will be displayed. If limit is bigger than 'CONF.api.max_limit' option of Nova API, limit 'CONF.api.max_limit' will be used instead.